# Loop condition does not stop the program

Tags: c, embedded, pic, mplab

```
void initTimer (void);
void delay (unsigned long milli);

unsigned int counter;
unsigned int zero =  0b0000000000000000;
unsigned int one =   0b0000000001000000;   

int main (void)
{
    initTimer();

    TRISB = 0;

    LATB = 0;

   for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
       LATB = zero;
       delay (SHORT_DELAY);
     
       LATB = one;
       delay (SHORT_DELAY);
      
   }
       while (1);
}
```

The code in the loop executes even after the counter crosses 10.The LEDS continue to flash. All variables are declared and all the number variables are binary, not sure if that means much.

Comment: Because you call the function over and over from a `for(;;)` loop per chance? Post the whole code.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: If this loop continue after counter crosses 10, that would mean you have a compiler bug. That's very unlikely. Please fix a [mre]

Comment: @Lundin initially had an outer while loop but it didnt affect the code, to my knowledge, so i removed it, but it doesnt seem to change the problem

Comment: @klutt I've shortened it to make it more understandable

Comment: MPLAB meaning some manner of PIC. Meaning returning from main() doesn't make sense. Because - surprise! It isn't a PC. You need `void main (void) { for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) { ...}  for(;;){} }`. Also check watchdog settings.

Comment: @Lundin ive used void main (void), but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: The `}` ending main is missing. Is there some code there you're not showing? And does the current code still cause the problem?

Comment: @klutt right my bad, i just forgot to add that in the question, its there though.  and yeah thats the rest of the code, nothing else to really show

Comment: Please put here the code you actually tested, and clean it up. Also include any possible configuration. One thing that comes to mind would be a watchdog reset that just restarts the program. Maybe include a different blink pattern at start to see when it actually starts.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to fix that, and fix indentation at the same time.

Comment: What happens if you introduce a longer delay after the for loop?

Comment: What is the meaning and consequences of `while(1);`?? Just remove it !!

Comment: @Damien it is supposed to be an infinite loop i think that stops the program? not sure i did it correctly but please let me know if i should replace it with something, but i believe this is what was referred to as the loop to be added to the end of the code

Comment: When you are at this line, the programme arrives at a dead end. It continues to do nothing an infinite number of times. It cannot get out of it.

Comment: @Damien is there a way to resolve it? because the initial problem was that the program wouldnt stop after the for loop, even if the counter crossed the condition value.

Comment: Why `counter` is global and not local variable? And BTW `0` is 10 times easier to read than `0b0000000000000000`. Don't understand what is the reason for binary "zero".

Comment: @i486hi, could you clarify why it should be a local variable and what would i replace it with?

Comment: I would do something like `const unsinged int bit_led = 0b0000000001000000;  // The bit used by the LED` and then to turn of `LATB &= ~bit_led;  // Turn off the led` and `LATB |= bit_led;  // Turn on the led` IMO a little easier to understand what's being done, and also doesn't touch the other unrelated bits. And `bit_led` is perhaps a little better name than `one` (which isn't really true for the value, since it's not `1`).

Comment: Have you switched off the watchdogtimer?

Comment: @Mike no and tbh im not sure how i would go about it, would you maybe mind elaborating on how i would do it?

Comment: You could switch oof the Watchdog in the configuration fuses. Or add `CLRWDT();`in your endless loop.

Comment: @Damien It's an embedded system bare metal microcontroller... I'll add the embedded tag now to scare the PC types away.

Comment: @Mike Seems like the answer. Is the watchdog enabled by default on PIC?

Comment: @lundin OK. Just note that originally this `while(1)` was not at the same place. And therefore my comment... I am not scared. I designed digital boards in the past ... :)

Comment: Yes, WDT enabled is default

Comment: @Mike You should wrap up those comments in an answer then, it's very likely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You had to switch off the watchdogtimer in your configuration, Something like:

```
__CONFIG _WDT_OFF
```

Otherwise the program will always be restartet and runs again thru your `for` loop