# Code does not stop at loop where condition is met

Tags: c, mplab

```
if ((PORTAbits.RA0 == 0) && (PORTAbits.RA1 == 0) && (PORTAbits.RA2 == 0))
   {
    while(1){
         
                LATBbits.LATB6 = 1;
                delay (SHORT_DELAY);
                LATBbits.LATB6 = 0;
                delay (SHORT_DELAY);
    }          
}
           

else if ((PORTAbits.RA2 == 1))
        {
           
         LATB = nine;
         delay (SHORT_DELAY);

         LATB = eight;
         delay (SHORT_DELAY);

         LATB = seven;
         delay (SHORT_DELAY);

         LATB = six;
         delay (SHORT_DELAY);
         
         }
```

All the inputs are zero and match up with the first if statement, and I am trying to get them to infinite loop, but it just moves on to the next statement.

Comment: bruh any help pls howd i get an upvote on the question but no reply

Comment: I don't know mplab, but can you set breakpoints and step through to see what's happening? Can you add trace to the code to print out the values it's testing and to show which code it's executing? Are there other options for you to debug this yourself?

Comment: And if you're completely positive that you've got everything correct in C it'd be worth checking the assembler generated for this to verify it's what you're expecting. But I'd be very surprised if this was a compiler error.

Comment: @Rup the mplab ide makes it really difficult to debug, at least from my experience, and with my lesser knowledge in C, it only becomes more difficult

Comment: I suspect it's the same problem as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982502/loop-condition-does-not-stop-the-program

Comment: So once again: What about the watchdogtimer?

Comment: @SK - 11BJ 816097 Rick Hansen S - How do you know that _All the inputs are zero_?